# Why do I have to use the keyword [open] in order launch mysql

Tags: mysql, macos

I have mysql installed on my mac (running  OSX Snow Leopard). According to everything I have seen, all I should have to do is type mysql at the command line to bring up the monitor. I do have /usr/local/mysql in my path.

Instead, I have to type open mysql. That opens the monitor. However, I cannot login as root. I tried sudo open mysql. That worked, but it still logs me in as @localhost.

What's up???

Thanks,

John

Comment: What happens when you just type `mysql`?

Comment: Whats wrong with `@localhost`? If the server is running at your machine then you log in from localhost....

Comment: In MySQL users have a name and a domain. If you're logging in as root, it would be `root@localhost` so `@localhost` isn't a full login.

How did you install MySQL? There's a number of different ways on OS-X and which one you used could make a big difference in the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `/usr/local/mysql` is usually the directory where MySQL installs on OS X. Try this command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

In addition, I start the local MySQL server using an alias:

```
alias mysqld="sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe"
```

Comment: I'm such a tard!! That did it Harold!! Thanks.